# Odoo new api : What is the equivalence of _prepare_order_line_move method in the new API?

Tags: odoo-12

I'm working in migrating from old API code to the new API code but stuck with the `_prepare_order_line_move` method.

Here is the old API code :

```
class purchase_order(osv.osv):
_name = 'purchase.order'
_inherit = 'purchase.order'

def _prepare_order_line_move(self, cr, uid, order, order_line, picking_id, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context={}        
    res=super(purchase_order,self)._prepare_order_line_move(cr, uid, order, order_line, picking_id, context)
    res['qty_uos2'] = order_line.product_qty
    res['uos_id2'] = order_line.product_uom.id
    res['product_qty'] = order_line.qty_uos2
    res['product_uos_qty'] = order_line.qty_uos2
    res['product_uom'] = order_line.uos_id2.id
    res['product_uos'] = order_line.uos_id2.id

    return res
```

Can you help me? Thank you very much.
PS : Odoo 8.0 to Odoo 12.0

Comment: Can you please mention the version? You can easily get help if you ask information packed question.

Comment: @YounisMahsud Odoo version 8 to Odoo version 12

Comment: @YounisMahsud, let me also edit the post

Comment: Please check _prepare_stock_moves method. I think it is the replacement of _prepare_order_line_move method.

Comment: @YounisMahsud, thank you, I will check it now